# Access File system Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App (.Net 4.5) and I have some static files stored on the filesystem that I want to read from, but I get a **System.UnauthorizedAccessException** like so

```
string template = string.Empty;
var file = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/EmailTemplates/" + fileName);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
     {
        template = File.ReadAllText(file); <-- Unauthorized Access Exception Here
     }
return template;
```

I know the best practice is Azure Storage, but how do I make this work this way?

Comment: What does the MapPath() path end up being? You have full write access to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`. (note: as long as you don't delete your web app, the storage under `site` is durable, just like Azure Storage).

Comment: The map path gives me the correct location (at least looking in Kudu) but it says invalid access

Comment: Can you please edit your question with more detail, including the full error, as well as which call is generating the error? (I'm assuming `ReadAllText()` but don't know for sure).

Comment: I do not have access to full error because it is using Release Build, all I have is the Exception Type and the path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) states about [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx), it could be caused by one of the following conditions:

> - path specified a file that is read-only.
>
> -or-
>
> - This operation is not supported on the current platform.
>
> -or-
>
> - path specified a directory.
>
> -or-
>
> - The caller does not have the required permission.

You could leverage kudu console and use [Attrib](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx) command to check the attributes for your files or directories. Also, you could try to use [TYPE](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) command to display the contents of your file or click the Edit button from the file list table as follows:

[image]

Also, I created a new web app and deployed my MVC application for displaying the files under the `App_Data` folder, it could work as expected, you could refer to [it](http://brucewebapp.azurewebsites.net/FileProcess/index).

**UPDATE:**

```
//method for getting files
public List<DownLoadFileInformation> GetFiles()
{
    List<DownLoadFileInformation> lstFiles = new List<DownLoadFileInformation>();
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data"));

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        lstFiles.Add(new DownLoadFileInformation()
        {

            FileId = i + 1,
            FileName = item.Name,
            FilePath = dirInfo.FullName + @"\" + item.Name
        });
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return lstFiles;
}

//action for downloading a file
public ActionResult Download(string FileID)
{
    int CurrentFileID = Convert.ToInt32(FileID);
    var filesCol = obj.GetFiles();
    string fullFilePath = (from fls in filesCol
                                where fls.FileId == CurrentFileID
                                select fls.FilePath).First();

    string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullFilePath);
    return File(fullFilePath, contentType, new FileInfo(fullFilePath).Name);
}
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
public ActionResult ViewOnline(string FileID)
{
    int CurrentFileID = Convert.ToInt32(FileID);
    var filesCol = obj.GetFiles();
    string fullFilePath = (from fls in filesCol
                                where fls.FileId == CurrentFileID
                                select fls.FilePath).First();
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullFilePath);
    return Content(text);
}
```

Comment: The only real difference is that I am doing this from an API not MVC, could you show me the snippet that reads the contents of the file?

Comment: I updated my answer with the related code snippet. I also checked using `File.ReadAllText` for retrieving the content of my json file.

Comment: Thanks,so you don't actually open the file in Code behind?

Comment: I updated my answer and added the `ViewOnline` action. You could check the file list and click the `View online` button.